# How do I deal with designing for screens of different resolutions, and/or my webpage becoming distorted when zooming in?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm a web-design novice, and I haven't found a way to deal with how my pages morphs if I `were` to zoom in, or use a different resolution screen. What are some tips for dealing with this?

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dtcrn/) of the page that I am working with so you guys can provide some directed advice as well.

That page looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMtcY.jpg) when it was designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I deal with designing for screens of different resolutions?

Look into using **[CSS3 Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)**:

> "A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions
>   that check for the conditions of particular media features. Among the
>   media features that can be used in media queries are ‘width’,
>   ‘height’, and ‘color’. By using media queries, presentations can be
>   tailored to a specific range of output devices without changing the
>   content itself."

Examples:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
  /* Media query targetting tablets */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 560px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* This media query will target the iPhone 5 only */
}
```

Of course it's better to place your queries seperately and not inline, so you'd import it externally like so:

```
<link href="aMediaQuery.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:500px)">
```

Comment: I'll definitely look into it,but if you'll notice on the link, it would vary greatly even if I zoomed in a single time, I feel that if I were to make queries for all these cases, I'd wind up with a ridiculous amount of them. Do you think you could take a look at the `#white_logo` and `#about_text_container` ids? I feel I'm going about this incorrectly

Comment: @louis, I'll have to take a look in a couple of hours if that's ok as gotta rest up before work. In most cases using 3/4 media queries will suffice (one for small phones, one for smartphone,  one for tablet/small laptop and one for large laptop/desktop

Comment: Absolutely, that would be much appreciated! I suspected as much, that does point to bad code in this case.

Comment: @Zenith It is not better to have the media queries in the link tag. Most browsers download them anyways (they will even download print stylesheets whether or not you use them) and that method adds another HTTP request which will slow down your page.

Comment: @bookcasey Obviously I meant in comparison to having them inline, which is never a good idea.

Comment: @Zenith It seems like you're saying the best practice is to include a different stylesheet for each breakpoint. Also, I don't think it's possible to include media queries "inline". You could use an internal style sheet with the `<style>`, which might even be a good thing for a tiny single page site. But as far as I know inline: `<div style="@media screen...` doesn't work.

Comment: @bookcasey Lol it's pretty obvious what I meant by inline, and it wasn't <div style="@media screen... Also I've never actually seen a 'one-page website', so using internal stylesheets are out of the question.

Comment: @Zenith http://onepagelove.com/